# Convert type String to System.Drawing.FontStyle

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that stores `FontStyle` in database. The value stored are either 'Regular', 'Bold', 'Italic'.

I have a property

```
public FontStyle FontStyle { get; set; }
```

When I am setting the value to the `FontStyle` I am getting the error

> Cannot Convert type 'String' to 'System.Drawing.FontStyle'.

I used:

```
MyLabel.FontStyle = (FontStyle)propertyValue;
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Enum.Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `FontStyle` property is actually declared as `FontStyle FontStyle {get; set;}` then you should be able to use

```
MyLabel.FontStyle = this.FontStyle;
```

But it sounds to me like you are using some intermediary variable named `propertyValue` and it is a string, not a `FontStyle` value. If that is the case, you can use

```
MyLabel.FontStyle = (FontStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FontStyle), propertyValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried `MyLabel.FontStyle = (FontStyle)Enum.Parse(propertyValue);` but getting an error `No overload for method 'Parse' takes 1 arguments`. But i already fixed it by doing some researched. Using `(FontStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FontStyle), propertyValue)`